# Unparsable Date exception with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, milliseconds

I'm trying to get milliseconds from a date but I got the exception

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jul 25 10:56:29 GMT+02:00 2019"

That's what I've done so far:

I took the date from a DatePicker with this pattern "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" and then passed to a method to get the milliseconds:

```
long milliDate = parseIso8601(dateTimeCalendar.getTime().toString());

private static long parseIso8601(String value) {
    try {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US).parse(value).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException ignored) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I got the exception and it returns 0. I don't know what's wrong. Thanks

Comment: i tried running your same code  parseIso8601("Thu Jul 25 10:56:29 GMT+02:00 2019") it is running on my machine

Comment: I cannot reproduce either. Your code runs fine on my desktop Java 11. As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: The date from your date picker is probably already a `Date` object. There’s no reason to convert it to a string and parse that string back into a `Date`. As another aside your method name `parseIso8601` is misleading. The format you are parsing has no similarity to ISO 8601.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in zone, zzz expect name of timezone, e.g. EST, GMT or other.

The correct pattern for your case:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'XXX yyyy
```

Comment: I don’t understand. [The docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) give `GMT-08:00` as an example of a time zone that matches pattern letter `z`, so I should say it should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Calendar object with the values from your DatePicker and TimePicker:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), 
             timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```